# Collecting weekly/daily numbers with Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I work for the Federal Govt and FormsCentral has allowed me to collect stats (numbers only) of people housed, applications submitted this week/day, etc. It collects them in an easy to read/neat spreadsheet with column headings. My staff can send weekly/daily updates from a smart phone, tablet, or computer and it will collect the responses for me. Does Cognito have this ability?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) has most of the features found in FormsCentral, as well as a lot of unique innovative features like powerful calculations and repeating sections.  Check out my blog post, which provides a detailed feature comparison of Cognito Forms versus Adobe FormsCentral:

http://blog.cognitoapps.com/feature-comparison-adobe-formscentral

Cognito Forms is designed to work well on computers, tablets and phones, both for submitting and managing entries.  You can view submitted data in a grid, though it is not an editable spreadsheet view like Adobe had.  You can also view and manage entries on your phone, as well as export data to Excel with a single click.

Feel free to write us on our home page if you have any other questions, or just sign up and starting using Cognito Forms!  You can quickly import your forms from Adobe FormsCentral here:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/l/Adobe-FormsCentral-Alternative